# How to embed image in RTE componet in CQ5

Tags: image, base64, aem, rte

I have a CQ5 component where the users can write some text with a richtext editor. It is also possible to paste Image script code into source editor available in RTE.

When I am pasting the source code as below

```
  <div style="background:url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');  height:100;width:100;"></div>
```

into RTE, It's getting converted as shown below and it is not rendering the image.

```
  <div style="background: url('data:image/png; base64,ivborw0kggoaaaansuheugaaaauaaaafcayaaacnbyblaaaaheleqvqi12p4//8/w38giaxdibke0dhxgljnbaao9txl0y4ohwaaaabjru5erkjggg==');  height: 100; width: 100;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Has anybody a suggestion what can be the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the code that is formatting the HTML is in `/libs/cq/ui/rte/core/HtmlSerializer.js` and/or `/libs/cq/ui/rte/core/HtmlProcessor.js` so you may need to override that by copying that file to apps as `/apps/cq/ui/rte/core/HtmlSerializer.js` and/or `/libs/cq/ui/rte/core/HtmlProcessor.js`.  This code is doing toLowerCase in several places, though I don't know specifically where it would be altering a style attribute value.  But I suspect it is.  One of those files has a comment that seems suspicious:

> // IE < 9 will report uppercase style names; hence normalize to
>   lowercase

So perhaps there is some code added to work around an IE bug that is messing up what you are wanting to do--essentially introducing a different bug while fixing an IE issue.